# Yocto recipe for embedding librosa

Tags: yocto, bitbake, librosa

I'm trying to add librosa in my Yocto image, but I can't make it build properly.
First I add librosa in my image and, when I build it, it obviously fails. Then I try to add the corresponding recipe in my Yocto project.

As I'm a beginner in Yocto, I use devtool to build a recipe for librosa, which appears in rpi-build/workspaces. Building goes further but finally fails due to further dependencies requirements.

To save time, I try to bitbake librosa alone and it fails, giving me the missing libraries.
I carry on adding those libraries with devtools and rebuilding but, during this process, I'm facing several problems, either on addition (for numba, I have a parsing error) or in the recipe name as it does not accept '_' in the name.
For example I have a failure on lazy_loader which cannot be found (my generated recipe names 'lazy-loader...'

I guess there is a smarter way to do this, but I could not find an example of a recipe for librosa

Has anyone ever done that ? any help appreciated

The Yocto version used is Honister (3.4)
The recipe generated is the following one, named librosa_0.10.1.bb

```
# Recipe created by recipetool
# This is the basis of a recipe and may need further editing in order to be fully functional.
# (Feel free to remove these comments when editing.)

SUMMARY = "Python module for audio and music processing"
HOMEPAGE = "https://librosa.org"
# WARNING: the following LICENSE and LIC_FILES_CHKSUM values are best guesses - it is
# your responsibility to verify that the values are complete and correct.
LICENSE = "ISC"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE.md;md5=25507c38058deac1239f865af7e6ed72"

SRC_URI = "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9a/c4/22a644b91098223d653993388daaf9af28175f2f39073269efa6f7c71caf/librosa-${PV}.tar.gz"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "a5060a34cb7f032d45f88a302fced076"
SRC_URI[sha1sum] = "cd51a9861457d600c97faa48c42ce716498a81ab"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "832f7d150d6dd08ed2aa08c0567a4be58330635c32ddd2208de9bc91300802c7"
SRC_URI[sha384sum] = "120d37f4a8f6e8434ecc60d7b050a5445794a1ec7c26a4d0f35bb587e64f771288306ddafaf63f6f615eb4e3a6b4e42a"
SRC_URI[sha512sum] = "501e1ce3e01c60e281d57e58f01a6781768d60071878989d346394e07acb799d1d25f380478b4c979a22893dd004e51d3c90eecccb6b1485c9194191f7996791"

inherit setuptools3

# The following configs & dependencies are from setuptools extras_require.
# These dependencies are optional, hence can be controlled via PACKAGECONFIG.
# The upstream names may not correspond exactly to bitbake package names.
#
# Uncomment this line to enable all the optional features.
#PACKAGECONFIG ?= "display docs tests"
PACKAGECONFIG[display] = ",,,python3-matplotlib"
PACKAGECONFIG[docs] = ",,,python3-ipython python3-matplotlib python3-mir_eval python3-numba python3-numpydoc python3-presets python3-sphinx! python3-sphinx-gallery python3-sphinx-multiversion python3-sphinx_rtd_theme python3-sphinxcontrib-svg2pdfconverter"
PACKAGECONFIG[tests] = ",,,python3-matplotlib python3-packaging python3-pytest python3-pytest-cov python3-pytest-mpl python3-resampy python3-samplerate python3-types-decorator"

# WARNING: the following rdepends are from setuptools install_requires. These
# upstream names may not correspond exactly to bitbake package names.
RDEPENDS:${PN} += "python3-audioread python3-decorator python3-joblib python3-lazy-loader python3-msgpack python3-numba numpy python3-pooch python3-scikit-learn python3-scipy python3-soundfile python3-soxr python3-typing-extensions"

# WARNING: the following rdepends are determined through basic analysis of the
# python sources, and might not be 100% accurate.
RDEPENDS:${PN} += "python3-core python3-json python3-shell"

# WARNING: We were unable to map the following python package/module
# dependencies to the bitbake packages which include them:
#    matplotlib.axes
#    matplotlib.cm
#    matplotlib.collections
#    matplotlib.colors
#    matplotlib.lines
#    matplotlib.markers
#    matplotlib.path
#    matplotlib.pyplot
#    matplotlib.ticker
#    numpy
#    numpy.lib.stride_tricks
#    numpy.typing
#    pkg_resources
#    scipy.fftpack
#    scipy.interpolate
#    scipy.ndimage
#    scipy.optimize
#    scipy.signal
#    scipy.sparse
#    scipy.spatial.distance
#    scipy.stats
#    sklearn
#    sklearn.cluster
#    sklearn.decomposition
#    sklearn.feature_extraction
#    sklearn.neighbors
```

Comment: Could you clarify which yocto version are you using ? Could you post the recipe you wrote to try compiling librosa ?

Comment: You could take a look at [pipoe](https://pypi.org/project/pipoe/) package to generate recipes recursively. But have to mention that creating yocto recipes for python packages is inherently a dirty work in 2023...

Comment: Thank you for the tip @skandigraun, I managed to create the recipe with all the dependencies. I also managed to set it in my image (I will post an edit to give more details), however, when building my image, it fails on not finding lazy_loader. My lazy_loader recipe is named lazy-loader ...